# I want to execute python in VS code. But VS Code Right Click not showing "Run Python File in Terminal" or "Run Selection/Line in python Terminal"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have installed VS Code version 1.71.2. I have installed extension Python and Code Runner. Python programs are getting executed thru command prompt.

[Commend prompt python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPyHT.png)

I opened above folder in VS code and executed manually program in terminal and it is ok.
[Manual execution in terminal py program.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN9cv.png)

However my other friend is using code runner in VS code and python programs are getting executed at his end flawlessly. In my pc it is showing error. Also he get many option on right click. like below

[Context Menu option in VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnN12.png)

In my case right click doesn't show option like "Run Python File in Terminal" or " Run selection/line in python terminal". Also python file doesn't get executed using run button. It shows error. I have added coderunner and python extensions.

[Context Menu options missing and error in python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvKbW.jpg)

So my questions is :

1. How to run python file in VS code using run button like code Runner.
2. How can I get context menu many options on right click like my friend.

I have tried Coderunner and python extensions. I don't know what needs to be done in settings.json file.
I am expecting python execution in VS code and getting list of options in context menu on right click.

Comment: This is part of the Python extension ([see user docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#:~:text=Select%20one%20or%20more%20lines,a%20part%20of%20a%20file.) and [GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/search?q=%22run+selection%22)). Do you have the Python extension installed an enabled?

Comment: use a launch config or use the Jupyther Notebooks or Python Interactive

Comment: Yes I have python extension and coderunner extension enabled.

Comment: Is your file's open editor's language mode set to python? You can see and change the language mode at the bottom right of the workspace

Comment: Great..!! Yes I am getting context menu options now after selecting python in language mode. I am able to execute programs successfully using Run python code in terminal options . But still python programs are not getting executed using code runner button

Comment: You need to create a `launch.json` run configuration for that button to work. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_run-hello-world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the tab icon is not two snake heads, representing a Python script, but rather a Windows icon, what it thinks is a shell script...

Also, your terminal is showing `cmd /c`, not `python` executing the script.

Make sure you have Python selected in the bottom right. Or change the file associations.

[image]

Or, you can create a `.ipynb` notebook file instead.

Also, 1.77 is the latest VSCode, so recommend you upgrade.

Comment: Yes I changed language mode and program is getting executed using run python file in terminal . But code runner play button giving error. [Running] python -u "d:\Study\Python\hello.py"
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Comment: You do not need CodeRunner extension

Answer (score 0):

I am getting context menu option on right click after changing language mode in bottom right workspace to python.

After that I was getting error while running using play button.
[Running] python -u "d:\Study\Python\hello.py"
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

I managed this by turning off python app aliases.
[Disable python app alias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t69N.png)

Now program is running smoothly. Thank you community.
[palindrome program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIlnT.png)